# Gradient of a Gaussian Quadratic Form

Tags: normal-distribution, optimal-control

For research purposes, I am solving a particular case of an optimal control problem. I need to compute
$$\nabla_{u_t} (x_t^TC^TQ_tv_t)   $$
where $x_t \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $ C \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times n}$ and $Q_t \in \mathbb{R}^{q \times q}$ do not depend on $u_t \in \mathbb{R}^m$, while the noise $v_t \in \mathbb{R}^q$ is $$ v_t \sim N(0,V_t(u_t)),$$
with covariance matrix $V_t$ which depends on $u_t$. The suffix $T$ denotes the transpose operator.

Does anyone know how to compute this?

Comment: Obscure. You may mean gradient of the expectation of  $Stuff\, (v_t)?$